# Understanding the IPC metric from Nvprof and GPGPUsim

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvprof

A Pascal SM has 4 scheduler per SM, when we get something like 3 as the IPC, does it mean 3 instructions where scheduled by the SM in a cycle?
Also, does NVPROF consider an average of the IPC of all SM for that Kernel and report it?

if one SM has an IPC of 3 then a GPU with 2 SM should give us an IPC of 6, right?

Also, I am working with a simulator called as GPGPU sim, which reports IPC in higher ranges (80-120)
I assume that they are calculating IPC per core and scaling the metric to the whole simulated GPU but I am not sure.

Can some one please verify the IPC metric?

Comment: How could a single core possibly execute 80 instructions per clock cyxle?

Comment: No, I did not mean that I meant, out of the 128 cores in an SM, 80 did execute and instruction in 1 cycle, while other were stalled for memory access or cache miss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NVPROF ipc metric is calculated as SUM(sm_inst_executed) / SUM(sm_active_cycles)

This results in the average IPC of a single SM. Maxwell/Pascal SMs have a maximum SM IPC of 6. Volta/Turing SMs have a maximum SM IPC of 4.

sm_inst_executed - The number of warp instructions executed counted at the point where the instruction must complete (cannot be rolled back due to speculative execution). Fully predicated off instructions are counted.

sm_active_cycles - The number of cycles the SM had at least 1 active/resident warp.

NVIDIA Perfworks provides the following metrics:

sm[sp]__inst_executed_{avg, sum}*per*{active, elapsed}_cycle.

The _sum variant is the total IPC (max is SM_COUNT * SM_MAX_IPC)
The _avg variant is the average IPC (SUM(sm__inst_executed) / SUM(sm__{active, elapsed}_cycle))
The elapsed_cycles variant includes cycles the SM is not active.